# Mixing '__try' and 'try' in single function - Through Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, exception, c++14, seh

It is known that Windows SEH doesn't go along with C++ exception handling mechanism. We cannot use `try` and `__try` in single function. This will lead to compiler error:

```
__try
{
   try
   {
       MayThrowCPPException_OR_SEH();
   }
   catch(...)
   {
   }
}
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
}
```

It will render:

> C2713: Only one form of exception handling permitted per function.

One option, which most people don't like is "Yes with SEH Exceptions (**/EHa**)" compiler option. This will facilitate C++ try/catch to handle both of the exception. We need to put such function in separate file, and put **/EHa** only for that source file.

Another option is to put `try` (or `__try`) in one function, and have another function which will have `__try`( or `try`).

**Question Begins**
While trying to do the above, I tried by just having a C++ lambda to fool the compiler. Here is what I did:

```
auto call_this =[] 
{
   MayThrowCPPException_OR_SEH();
   // C++ exception handling here.
};
__try
{
   call_this();
}
__except(...)
{
}
```

And this compiled fine on VC++ 2013 update 5.

Is it safe to do so?

Comment: this doesn't compile on my VS 2013..

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: that the lamda itself requiers stack unwinding, which is the reason you wanted to use lambda in the first place

Comment: I got (slightly) same error. A function having __try cannot have C++ objects. It has nothing to do with lambda.

Comment: @Ajay a lambda is a C++ object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is safe. The lambda body is just an `operator()` method of an unnamed lambda type. This method has the C++ exception handler. The outer function has the SEH handler.

Comment: I wouldn't crown this answer as correct so fast. I wasn't able to build this code on my VS, but I'm afraid that when hardware produced exception is thrown, it doesn't call the destructors of every object it finds, like regular C++ exception does. I wasn't able  to verify it since I can't compile the code, but this is something that one needs to check before saying this is safe. the program may not crash, but the objects inside teh lambda may be in a very bad codition.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Indeed. The SEH functionality exists at the OS level. The OS doesn't know about destructors, so it won't call them. But that's unrelated to the problem here (mixing exception handlers). That's why I say that this method is safe: it assumed that you already had SEH-safe code.

Comment: @DavidHaim, I do agree with RAII pattern. __try isn't meant for that, and I didn't say that.

Comment: @DavidHaim, And I also see why you might not reproduce the success. If you have a lambda containing C++ try, followed by a call, wrapped in SEH, it works. If you put another lambda after __try, it fails to compile. Try various combination, only the one I provided in question works. Very much a compiler bug (non-consistent).

Comment: @Ajay, do you have C++ objects with destructors in scope? Because David does have a valid point. SEH and destructors are locally incompatible. This includes the destructor of a **capturing** lambda.

Comment: @MSalters, I don't have any such C++ objects. When compiler sees both __try/try, it raises error. But when you keep `__try` inside a lambda, and then a `try` in function it doesn't say a word. But. If you have `try` at function level and then have `__try` inside a lambda, it raises error. Seems logical bug in parser. And yes, am aware that RAII and SEH don't go together.